# cannot resolve(getsupportfragmentmanager,java.lang.string)

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I'm getting the error in material date picker, datepicker.show method.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import  android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private TextView textView;
    private View btnPickDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        btnPickDate = findViewById(R.id.btn_date);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                MainActivity.this,
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR), // Initial year selection
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH), // Initial month selection
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) // Inital day selection
        );

        // If you're calling this from a support Fragment
        dpd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year;
        dateTextView.setText(date);
    }
}
```

this document says, if using the AppCompatActivity should use the getSupportFromFragmentManager(). but it's not working.

[materialdatepicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

Comment: If you're using a recent version of that library, it has migrated to androidx, so it's expecting an `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager`. You're still using the old support classes, so `getSupportFragmentManager()` is returning an `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`.

Comment: @MikeM. So what is the old version of library... I don’t find the old version which support v4.

Comment: I need to change entire application

Comment: OK, their release notes are decent, so it was trivial to find. MaterialDateTimePicker v3.6.4 was the last version before the androidx update. Please note, though, that you shouldn't expect users here to find off-site resources for you. We actually have a specific close reason for that.